# Mongoose problems with $gte

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to filter items by price by range, but for some reason only the maximum value works when filtering, the minimum value is just kind of ignored.

My MongoSchema:

```js
  const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  variants: [
    {
      discount: {
        state: { type: Boolean, required: true },
        percent: { type: String, required: true },
      },
      price: { type: Number, required: true },
      ...
    },
  ],
});
```

My search via find method with filter passing

```js
export const getProducts = (filter: any) => ProductModel.find(filter);
```

My filtering function:

```js
const priceArray = (price as string).split("-");
const priceFilter = { 'variants.price': { $gte: 1001, $lte: 10000 }};

if (categories !== "all") {
      const categoriesArray = (categories as string).split(",");
      categoriesFilter = { categoryID: { $in: categoriesArray } };
    }

    const query = {
      ...categoriesFilter,
      ...priceFilter,
    }

    const products = await getProducts(query)
      .sort({ _id: sort === "asc" ? 1 : -1 })
      .skip((Number(page) - 1) * Number(limit))
      .limit(Number(limit))
      .populate([
        "categoryID",
        "variants.ingredients.ingredient.id",
        "variants.ingredients.ingredient.variantID",
      ])
      .exec();
```

This code correctly filters by category and also filters by price (but as I described above, it does not take into account the minimum value and filters only by the maximum value).

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `variants` is an array, you should use [$elemMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

```js
const priceFilter = { 
  "variants": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "price": {
        "$gte": 1001,
        "$lte": 10000
      }
    }
  }
};
```

[Working Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AOJ2f2oAfSH)